# SQL get from match two column

Tags: mysql

I have my table something like this:

```
+------------------+-------------------+-----------+
|       name       +  student_number   +   date    |
-------------------+-------------------+-----------|
| Daniel           | 2014-10445        | 9-23-15   |
| Eden             | 2014-10420        | 9-23-15   |
| Nadine           | 2014-10012        | 9-24-15   |
| Eden             | 2014-10420        | 9-25-15   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the value from second row which contains '2014-10420' in column name student_number and '9-23-15' in date column.

I have here my query: `SELECT date,student_number FROM attendance WHERE date='9-23-15' AND student_number='2014-10420'` but also returning other rows containing '9-23-15'

How can I get the two match column??

Comment: Also, what point is there in selecting only the two columns whose values you already know (since they are fixed by the filter criteria)?  The only useful information you'd obtain from that is the number of matching records, which would more efficiently be obtained by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`.

Comment: @eggyal: only one row (=2) matches the where clause, row 1 has a different student number, row 4 has different date.  Agree with 2nd comment though.

Comment: @PaulF: Good point—I thought the dates matched.  Comment deleted.

Comment: Query does look alright to me - you say the table looks _"something like this"_. Is that exactly how it looks - can you create an SQLFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I've mocked it up as per this table and it works as I would expect. How have you got the dates formatted? MYSQL can be very funny with dates, so I have a feeling that could be your issue

Comment: Apart from month-day order - here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d7fc7/6) which works with OP query

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this one:

```
SELECT date,student_number FROM attendance WHERE (date='9-23-15' AND student_number='2014-10420') or date='9-23-15'
```

Is this the logic you are looking for?

Comment: Isn't that just the same as _date='9-23-15' OR student_number='2014-10420'_? But the OP only wants one row back NOT both rows.

Comment: It's not the same since I think he does not want user '2014-10420' on the other days.

Comment: OP says _I want to get the value from second row which contains '2014-10420' in column name student_number and '9-23-15' in date column._ but later says he is getting both rows with date '9-23-15'. I understand his question as asking how does he get the query to match date AND the student number - so only returning the second row. If I am misunderstanding the question - then you may be right of course.